# Is it possible to control the render order of a path of a THREE.Line using the SVGRenderer?

Tags: svg, three.js, path

I am generating a (self avoiding) random line and render it with the SVGRenderer. It all works fine so far and the result looks like I expected. Now I would like to animate the SVG path with this simple trick: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/.

Unfortunately this does not work properly since the SVG path is not drawn in the same order as the points in the THREE.BufferGeometry I am using to render THREE.Line.

The points in the THREE.BufferGeometry look like this:
[Screenshot of THREE.BufferGeometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFHui.png)

The path in the SVG looks like this:

```
<path d="M-91.23724729581473,46.981849249447244L22.80931182395362,13.667447054384706M22.80931182395362,13.667447054384706L91.23724729581463,69.19145071282227M-91.23724729581473,-69.19145071282213L-91.23724729581473,46.981849249447244M91.23724729581463,-46.981849249447095L22.80931182395362,-102.50585290788467M91.23724729581463,69.19145071282227L-22.80931182395371,102.50585290788482M-22.80931182395371,102.50585290788482L-22.80931182395371,-13.667447054384558M-22.80931182395371,-13.667447054384558L91.23724729581463,-46.981849249447095" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:15;stroke-linecap:round"></path>
```

When I inspect the SVG path [with this nice tool](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) I see that the lines in the SVG path are not "in order":

First line:
[Frist line in SVG path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKyua.png)

Second line:
[Second line in SVG path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIlvv.png)

Third line:
[Third line in SVG path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H73L.png)

Forth line:
[Fourth line in SVG path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23E5u.png)

I am wondering if there is an option to customize/adjust the order of the lines in the SVG path by passing the order to the SVGRenderer? If yes, how would I do that in a nice way?

Instead of using the "Move To" M command the lines should be drawn one after another without moving after each line command. Ideally there would even be a way to render a `<polyline>` instead of a `<path>`.

Thanks for your help!

I did try to find out more about the functionality of the SVGRenderer but do not really get how I could customize it…

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw the `<path>` in a specific order, you're gonna have to manually re-position the values of the `d` attribute. I recommend you read the [Paths MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) first, to get acquainted with what the two commands `M (move)` and `L (line)` mean.

For starters, I don't think you need 15 decimals of precision. Nobody needs to draw a billionth of a pixel. So I've rounded from `M-91.23724729581473,46.981849249447244` to `M-91.2,47.0`

```html
<path d="
M-91.2,47.0    // Move to 91,47
L22.8,13.7     // Line to 22,13
M22.8,13.7     // Move to 22,13 (Redundant: we were already at this position)
L91.2,69.2     // Line to 91,69
M-91.2,-69.2   // Move to -91,-69 (Why move away to a new position?)
L-91.2,47.0    // Line
M91.2,-47.0    // Why move away again, instead of just continue the line?
L22.8,-102.5
M91.2,69.2     // Move again
L-22.8,102.5
M-22.8,102.5   // Move again...
L-22.8,-13.7
M-22.8,-13.7
L91.2,-47.0
">
```

As you can see, your path is very fragmented: drawing a single line, then moving away to a new starting point, to draw another line segment somewhere else. If you want one contiguous line, you should not use as many "Moves" and just draw from one line endpoint to the next:

```html
<!-- Same shape, no jumping around, in half the code -->
<path d="
M-91.2,-69.2
L-91.2,47
L22.8,13.7
L91.2,69.2
L-22.8,102.5
L-22.8,-13.7
L91.2,-47
L22.8,-102.5
">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Exactly, the fragmented paths are the problem. Since I didn't write the path myself but it is generated by the SVGRenderer of three.js, I wanted to find out with my question whether I can specify the render order through options of the SVGRenderer.

But thank you for your comments on the SVG paths! Is there a way to programmatically sanitize SVG paths like you did manually in your answer?

Comment: Oh, I see… the unordered lines is what the SVGRenderer outputs? Then no, I don’t have an answer for you. It probably does this on purpose to handle depth order or something like that.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway (especially for pointing out the specifics of SVG path commands)! 